# typeorm convert EntitySchema to Entity

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using typescript and typeorm. I have this Entity:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Sample {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ length: 50 })
    name: string;

    @Column('text', { nullable: true })
    description: string;
}
```

I query a single result like this:

```
const connection = await this.getConnection();
const sampleRepo = await connection.getRepository(Sample);
const sample = await sampleRepo.createQueryBuilder('sample')
    .where('sample.id = :id', { id: id })
    .getOne();
```

Now, I need to do some stuff with the result columns, but the sample object is of type `EntitySchema`. So, in typescript, I can't do `sample.id` because the error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EntitySchema<any>'
```

Is there anyway to convert the `EntitySchema` into an actual `Sample` object?

Comment: I'm guessing that your sampleRepo is improperly created. It should be something like `getRepository(Sample)`

Comment: I added how I'm creating the repository

Comment: Hmm that ought to work. It's what's in the documentation

Comment: You might want to start by trying: const sample = await getRepository(Sample).createQueryBuilder('sample')
    .where('sample.id = :id', { id: id })
    .getOne();` Chaining these promises might be having an adverse effect and breaking a reference somewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is due to a bad implementation. I moved the creation of the repository to a separate class:

```
export default class Database {
    private connectionManager: ConnectionManager

    constructor() {
        this.connectionManager = getConnectionManager();
    }

    public getRepository<T extends EntitySchema>(type:  ObjectType<T> | EntitySchema<T> | string): Promise<Repository<T>> {
        const connection = await this.getConnection();
        return connection.getRepository(type);
    }

    public async getConnection(connectionName = 'default'): Promise<Connection> {
        let connection: Connection;

        if (this.connectionManager.has(connectionName)) {
            connection = this.connectionManager.get(connectionName);

            if (!connection.isConnected) {
                connection = await connection.connect();
            }
        }
        else {
            const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = Object
                .assign({ name: connection }, connectionProperties);

            connection = await createConnection(connectionOptions);
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

It looks like `connection.getRepository` doesn't return a promise. As well, the `T` generic shouldn't be extending `EntitySchema`. To make the function work as intended, I had to write it like this:

```
public getRepository<T>(type:  ObjectType<T> | EntitySchema<T> | string): Promise<Repository<T>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.getConnection().then(conn => {
            resolve(conn.getRepository(type));
        }).catch(reject);
    });
}
```